# How to define animation height Confines

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, animation

i have created animation but my fishes get out the fish tank aquerium how can i confines it?

here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/832Fx/3/

here is some code example:

```
var $wnd = $('.fishtank');
$wnd.resize(function() {
    animeVars.rightMargin = $wnd.width();
    animeVars.bottomMargin = $('.fishtank').height();
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cool fish.

This is somewhat strange:

```
var newCoords = {
  top: Math.random() * (animeVars.topMargin - animeVars.bottomMargin + 1) + animeVars.bottomMargin,
  left: Math.random() * (animeVars.leftMargin - animeVars.rightMargin + 1) + animeVars.rightMargin
};
```

What you're trying to do, I think, is pick a random position on an axis between X from the start and Y from the end:

```
      X                    Y
    |---|--------------|-------|
```

Then you'll want to do something like this:

```
pos = Math.random() * (canvasWidth - X  Y) + X;
```

I'm sure you have the canvas width somewhere: `$wnd.width()`.

Comment: the width is the '.fishtank' where should i put it? can u help me stand it?

Comment: If you made that fishtank, I'm sure you can figure out where to get the canvas/window/fishtank width. And you know where to get `X` and `Y`.